# Creating Forms in Slack to Jira Tickets

Tags: forms, jira, slack

I want to create a simple form in Slack that contains :
text boxes, radio button selections, checkboxes and list selection boxes.

I want that the form will interact and open a ticket in Jira from Slack.
I herd it's possible but I don't know how to do it.

Please help,
thank you very much.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. StackOverflow is for programmers who have a programming problem where they have attempted some code and can't get it to work. Make an attempt and submit where you are having problems. Read the help on writing a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is only partly possible with Slack. You can do something called a [Dialog](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) in Slack, which is a kind of modal form. But it currently only supports three types of input fields:

- input
- inputarea
- select

No radio buttons or check-boxes.

Check out the excellent [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/) for details.

Comment: Note that Slack has now added support for other types of input field.